# Using konsole to emulate a terminal through Perl

Tags: linux, perl, raspberry-pi, konsole

I have an issue when using this command

```
system("konsole --new-tab --workdir<dir here> -e perlprogram.pl &");
```

It opens perlprogram.pl which has:

```
system("mpg321 song.mp3");
```

I want to do this because mpg321 stalls the main perl script. so i thought by opening it in another terminal window it would be ok. But when I do run the first script all it does is open a new tab and do nothing.

Am I using konsole correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I using `konsole` correctly?

Likely, no. But that depends. This question can be decomposed into two issues:

1. How do I achieve concurrency, so that my program doesn't halt while I execute an external command
2. How do I use `konsole`.

#### 1. Concurrency

There are multiple ways to do that. Starting with the `fork||exec('new-program')`, to `system 'new-program &'`, or even `open`.

`system` will invoke the standard shell of your OS, and execute the command you provided. If you provide multiple arguments, no shell escaping is done, and the specified program `exec`ed directly. (The `exec` function has the same interface so far). `system` returns a number that specifies if the command ran correctly:

```
system("my-command", "arg1") == 0
  or die "failed my-command: $?";
```

See `perlfunc -f system` for the full info on what this return value signifies…

The `exec` never returns if successfull, but morphs your process into executing the new program.

`fork` splits your process in two, and executes the child and the process as equal copies. They *only* differ in the return value of `fork`: The parent gets the PID of the child; the child gets zero. So the following executes a command asynchronously, and lets your main script execute without further delay.

```
my @command = ("mpg321", "song.mp3");
fork or do {
  # here we are in the child
  local $SIG{CHLD} = 'IGNORE'; # don't pester us with zombies
  # set up environment, especially: silence the child. Skip if program is well-behaved.
  open STDIN, "<", "/dev/null" or die "Can't redirect STDIN";
  open STDOUT, ">", "/dev/null" or die "Can't redirect STDOUT";
  exec {$command[0]} @command;
  # won't ever be executed on success
  die qq[Couldn't execute "@command"];
};
```

The above process effectively daemonizes the child (runs without a tty).

#### 2. konsole

The command line interface of that program is awful, and it produces errors half the time when I run it with any parameters.

However, your command (plus a working directory) should actually work. The trailing ampersand isn't neccessary, as the `konsole` command returns immediately. Something like

```
# because I `say` hello, I can be certain that this actually does something.
konsole --workdir ~/wherever/ --new-tab -e perl -E 'say "hello"; <>'
```

works fine for me (opens a new tab, displays "hello", and closes when I hit enter). The final readline there keeps the tab open until I close it. You can keep the tab open until after the execution of the `-e` command via `--hold`. This allows you to see any error messages that would vanish otherwise.